# 2000 Toyota Sienna Rear Blinker Assembly Clips Broke Off

Tags: toyota, sienna

I recently took off the tail light on our 2000 Toyota Sienna and the clips on the light assembly side broke off as I was pulling it off. Any idea where I can get replacement clips? Or would I have to replace the whole assembly?

Comment: Which side broke tabs? Are you talking about the receptacle (hole) in the lens assembly or are you talking about the part which holds the bulb?

Comment: It's the driver side. You have the screws that old in the right side, then on the side there were pins of sorts that went into a hole in the side of the van. The pins broke off when the assembly was removed.

Comment: So the pins were in the assembly, which were probably there to align it with the body correctly?

Comment: Correct, otherwise the side of the light is very loose (I have it "secured", redneck style right now) and with driving wouldn't be good due to wind drag.

Comment: JeremyT, I have the EXACT same issue and I just want to buy the pins. Have you had any luck finding them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your comments, my suggestion to you is to replace the assembly. If you still have the pins, you could possible repair the assemply by using some (possibly) super glue or maybe even some epoxy. This approach, while cheaper, will never be as strong as new, as well as it may not align correctly once completed.

As a cost saving approach in lieu of purchasing a new assembly, you could alternatively try a wrecking yard or even look for part-outs on Craigslist. This may save you a few dollars in the end. These assemblies new from the dealership (affectionately called a "stealership") can be extremely pricey.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Paulster! The assembly isn't too expensive so I'm not too worried about that, though was hoping I could just get the pins. I'd vote you up, but I don't have the rep for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found replacement parts for this which might be useful. The number is:

> 9046717016

The cost about 1.50 each.

Just walk into any Toyota garage and ask if you can order that part in, and it should be ready in a few days for you. Most garages can order parts in for you, if you get a really bad garage just go to the next one, most of them will be happy to help.

NOTE: I have not actually ordered them so I don't know if they will really fit or not, but I think they will.